# HighCharts Generated Table

Tags: highcharts, formatting

I really need help on this.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885092/highcharts-with-datatable) I am trying to generate table from High-charts.

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kEFHx/) table is generated ok, but I need data values to be in text, not in number format.

I think format need to be changed at this line, but I am not sure ...

```
Highcharts.numberFormat(series[i].data[category_index].y, valueDecimals) + valueSuffix,
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: You need data values in text - what does that mean? How is "9.5 C" not text?

Comment: C is valueSuffix added to data trough function. What I need is to format data so I can use text and not just numbers in series data. So Tokyo will have options like 'one', 'two', '9.5 C' ... etc, witch is not available with curent script.

Comment: @Ivan, it is still not clear how "7.0 C" as shown in your jsFiddle does not meet your requirements. What is the expected text for "7.0 C"?

Comment: OK, I will try again ... I need in table to show cities ... names ... words, and with this script setup it can't be done ... Right now, its possible to enter only numbers as data value for each set (Tokyo, New York, Berlin) ... Go to Fiddle and try to enter any text in (data: [23, 6.9, 9.5 ....]) I don't need Celsius in textual format ... I don't need Celsius at all, forget about Celsius  ... Its just in Fiddle example

Comment: @Ivan, okay that makes more sense. However, you cannot do that. Values in series data must be of a numeric format while categories can be text. Have you tried displaying category text instead? I am looking into another possible way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why you could not replace the data values with text and have it show up are because you are defining the data types as decimal and using the `Highcharts.numberFormat` to make the y values into a decimal. Since you try to put in text it cannot format the string as a decimal so it is null. Now, you cannot simply take out that `Highcharts.numberFormat` call and have this work. A HighCharts data series requires a numeric y value. So, to do what you want we use an undocumented point property called `Note`.

Here is my attempt.
If what you want is to just use HighCharts to create a table in SVG/VML you can do the following.
Create a data series like this:

```
{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [{
            y: 7.0,
            Note: 'note 1'},
        {
            y: 6.9,
            Note: 'note 2'},
        {
            y: 9.5,
            Note: 'note 3'},
        {
            y: 14.5,
            Note: 'note 4'},
        {
            y: 18.2,
            Note: 'note 5'},
        {
            y: 21.5,
            Note: 'note 6'},
        {
            y: 25.2,
            Note: 'note 7'},
        {
            y: 26.5,
            Note: 'note 8'},
        {
            y: 23.3,
            Note: 'note 9'},
        {
            y: 18.3,
            Note: 'note 10'},
        {
            y: 13.9,
            Note: 'note 11'},
        {
            y: 9.6,
            Note: 'note 12'}
                                        ],
        visible: false}
```

Now, instead of looping on the `y` values you will loop over the `Note` items just like you had before only with the numeric stuff removed:

```
$.each(series, function(i) {
    renderer.text(series[i].data[category_index].Note, cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding, tableTop + (i + 2) * rowHeight - cellPadding).attr({
        align: 'right'
    }).add();
});
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/zRkgQ/1/) (with just one series updated to use the `Note` syntax but you get the idea).

Comment: @JohnnyHK, a lot has changed in 3 years. The fundamental code should point you in the right direction though. Here is live, kind of working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zRkgQ/218/. Note that I do not render graph and only Tokyo has `note` items added to table.