# How to display HighCharts with tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am trying to display table data in through `highcharts` along with table. But somehow chart and table is not getting display in html page. My code is below. Do I need to write down between `<div>` tag ? If I print normal text it gets display.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>
        charts
    </title>
    <script src="js/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /**
        * Create the data table
        */
        Highcharts.drawTable = function () {
            // user options
            var tableTop = 310,
                colWidth = 100,
                tableLeft = 20,
                rowHeight = 20,
                cellPadding = 2.5,
                valueDecimals = 1,
                valueSuffix = ' °C';
            // internal variables
            var chart = this,
                series = chart.series,
                renderer = chart.renderer,
                cellLeft = tableLeft;
            // draw category labels
            $.each( chart.xAxis[0].categories, function ( i, name ) {
                renderer.text(
                    name,
                    cellLeft + cellPadding,
                    tableTop + ( i + 2 ) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                ).css( {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                } ).add();
            } );
            $.each( series, function ( i, serie ) {
                cellLeft += colWidth;
                // Apply the cell text
                renderer.text(
                    serie.name,
                    cellLeft - cellPadding + colWidth,
                    tableTop + rowHeight - cellPadding
                ).attr( {
                    align: 'right'
                } ).css( {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                } ).add();

                $.each( serie.data, function ( row, point ) {

                    // Apply the cell text
                    renderer.text(
                        Highcharts.numberFormat( point.y, valueDecimals ) + valueSuffix,
                        cellLeft + colWidth - cellPadding,
                        tableTop + ( row + 2 ) * rowHeight - cellPadding
                    )
                        .attr( {
                            align: 'right'
                        } )
                        .add();

                    // horizontal lines
                    if ( row == 0 ) {
                        Highcharts.tableLine( // top
                            renderer,
                            tableLeft,
                            tableTop + cellPadding,
                            cellLeft + colWidth,
                            tableTop + cellPadding
                        );
                        Highcharts.tableLine( // bottom
                            renderer,
                            tableLeft,
                            tableTop + ( serie.data.length + 1 ) * rowHeight + cellPadding,
                            cellLeft + colWidth,
                            tableTop + ( serie.data.length + 1 ) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                        );
                    }
                    // horizontal line
                    Highcharts.tableLine(
                        renderer,
                        tableLeft,
                        tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding,
                        cellLeft + colWidth,
                        tableTop + row * rowHeight + rowHeight + cellPadding
                    );

                } );

                // vertical lines
                if ( i == 0 ) { // left table border
                    Highcharts.tableLine(
                        renderer,
                        tableLeft,
                        tableTop + cellPadding,
                        tableLeft,
                        tableTop + ( serie.data.length + 1 ) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                    );
                }

                Highcharts.tableLine(
                    renderer,
                    cellLeft,
                    tableTop + cellPadding,
                    cellLeft,
                    tableTop + ( serie.data.length + 1 ) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                );
                if ( i == series.length - 1 ) { // right table border
                    Highcharts.tableLine(
                        renderer,
                        cellLeft + colWidth,
                        tableTop + cellPadding,
                        cellLeft + colWidth,
                        tableTop + ( serie.data.length + 1 ) * rowHeight + cellPadding
                    );
                }

            } );
        };
        /**
        * Draw a single line in the table
        */
        Highcharts.tableLine = function ( renderer, x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {
            renderer.path( ['M', x1, y1, 'L', x2, y2] )
                .attr( {
                    'stroke': 'silver',
                    'stroke-width': 1
                } )
                .add();
        }
        /**
        * Create the chart
        */
        window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart( {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                events: {
                    load: Highcharts.drawTable
                },
                borderWidth: 2
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Average monthly temperatures'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                }
            },
            legend: {
                y: -300
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        } );
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/testing-exporting.js"></script>
    <div id="container" style="height: 600px;margin-top:20px;width: 600px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to use `Highcharts` before loading `Highcharts.js`, it should be `undefined` and js compile time error occurred...

Answer (score 6):

View this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/export-data/showtable/). 
Reference from the highcharts API under [showTable](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.showTable).

The above example simply adds this line of code to the chart object.. see link for full code:

`exporting: {
        showTable: true
    }`

There is another example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/studies/exporting-table/)
Referenced from the highcharts [FAQ - adding data table to exported chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table)

Comment: Hi, how could you add extra column to the table? For instance, view "ref" in brackets alongside the "y" value in : data: [{y:32093,ref:"Manager3"}, {y:24064,ref:"Manager3"}]

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading your question correctly you want to have HighCharts also "draw" a table containing the data as well as a chart of the data in that table.
If so, have a look at my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887074/highcharts-generated-table/12915639#12915639) question. It is regarding formatting of numeric values but my jsFiddle will show you how to draw the table.
Note that the formatting and alignment of the table/chart is tricky depending on how much data you are trying to show.